# External JavaScript files not working in Rails

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have created a new Rails 4 project and I am trying to load an external JavaScript file in my HTML file. I have placed the JavaScript file in the `/assets/javascripts` directory and included the file in my HTML file.

My HTML file:

```
<html>

    <body>
        <script src="/assets/hello.js"></script>
    </body>


</html>
```

My JavaScript file:

```
document.write("test");
```

I do not see any errors in my web browser console when loading the website. I am pretty sure I put the JavaScript file in to correct directory but the file will not run. Does Rails require something for external JavaScript files to work properly?

I have also tried defining a method in the JavaScript file and calling it within a `<script>` tag but I get a "Uncaught ReferenceError: methodname is not defined".

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to list 'assets/hello.js' in application.js. The Rails asset pipeline compiles all JavaScript into application.js based on the filepaths that it finds listed there.

More info here: http://railsapps.github.io/rails-javascript-include-external.html

Comment: I have tried that, but after reading the link you provided, `//= require_tree .` should recursively compile all js files. The js is still not working properly.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured out why Rails wasn't loading my JavaScript file. When I created the Rails project, it included `.coffee` scripts which can be used instead of JavaScript. For some reason by default, the `.coffee` script was being run instead of the JavaScript file that I created. After deleting the `.coffee` script, my JavaScript loads as expected.